# How to make m3u8 file play normally after decrypting TS file

Tags: m3u8

I have a series of encrypted ts files, and a m3u8 file below, it plays good with video player.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="v.key"
#EXTINF:3.014160,
hd-kUPE5cpako-0.ts
#EXTINF:3.014160,
hd-kUPE5cpako-1.ts
#EXTINF:3.014160,
hd-kUPE5cpako-2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I have decrypted every ts file via python, and each ts fils also play well with video player.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key = open('key', 'rb').read()
cryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, key)
```

howerver,when I remove the line **#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="v.key"** in m3u8 file, the m3u8 file can not be played in video player any more.

Comment: Do the ts files play in VLC?

Comment: Yes, I alseo tried othrer players, none of them seem to be working

Comment: What? Yes, the files dont play? is that like "Yes we have no bananas"? That is very confusing. Do the files play, or not?

Comment: sorry，I didn't read your last reply clearly，the ts files is player normally with VLC，but the m3u8 file is not